# how to get dropped file in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

we can get info of a file uploaded using input file type.But i was wondering if i use drag and drop to upload file ,how i can get file info in php.I searched the web but couldn't find any good tutorial on this topic.

In case of input type we can use the name attribute to get hold of the uploaded file data.But as we have to use a div for drag and drop ,how can i use php to do similar kind of thing.I am using the following code that i got from a tutorial:

currently i have no hint how to do this.Give me some hint or example so that i can go ahead on my own

```js
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
  }

  // Setup the dnd listeners.
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
    #drop_zone{
 
     width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px dashed gray;
  text-align:center;
  color:gray;
  font-size:25px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a "drag and drop" action you are doing it on the client side, so it means you have to handle the file which you are dropping into a div. Then you have to upload the file somehow.

You could create a fake/hidden file field. And when the file gets dropped into the div you can access it via the HTML5 FileAPI and put it virtually into the hidden file field and submit the form or send the form data via ajax to your php script on the server.

It means the drag and drop functionality has nothing to do, how it's handled on the server and vice-versa.